How to resolve error code":-32010,"message":"2UR.... excluded from account secondary indexes; this RPC method unavailable for key
I have set up a Solana full node with a configuration of 1TB memory for eypc 64 core.
At the same time, I also opened the account index program id spl token mint spl token owner
But when using getTokenLargestAccounts, I still encounter errors, and I found that my node memory only occupies 200g, it seems that the index was not established correctly? But the node is running normally without any errors, and it has been closely following the development of the block. How should I solve this problem.


Are you sure you have set your RPC to your server and not still using mainnet?

Yes, and I have tested other commands without any problems, with low latency, except for the command related to account index

I'm not sure on this, but maybe the mainnet-beta RPC does not support this geyser plugin?
Do you mind trying with a paid / free trial verson from Triton?

If you want to index all of the token accounts for a particular mint, you need to include that mint id in the account indexes, so in your startup script, try adding:
--account-index-include-key 2URzn...

Here's the code for reference that's returning the error that you see: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/5c0f173b88e757ca223b853d32e5fb995ade5479/rpc/src/rpc.rs#L2176
